What is the difference between delay and deadline timeouts in jitter backoff
I have once concern related to retry mechanism by using the Jitter.
When I try to hit the API calls sometimes we are getting failed response. That time we have implemented the retry mechanism.
I have little bit confusion for these both words.
From my point of view both are same.
Anyone can share your opinion what is the difference between the deadline and timeout while apply the jitter concept formula.
